# Is ViewGroup with id android.R.id.content always FrameLayout?

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout

In my activity I get a root view by code:

```
ViewGroup root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Debugger shows me that `root` variable is instance of `FrameLayout`.
My Question is: "Android guarantees to me that `root` always will be a `Framelayout` on all devices and on all api versions?"

Comment: why do you need to cast it to `FrameLayout`?

Comment: I want to create a universal code for set a progress bar to any activity. I want to use that FrameLayout to put a loader to activity, covering all other views

Comment: so make a base `Activity` and override its `setContentView` method, then let all your activities extend that base one

Comment: What code shoud be in overriden `setContentView` method?

Comment: `super.setContentView(newRootViewWithProgressBarAndYourOriginalView);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would rely that android.R.id.content will be of type ViewGroup but not FrameLayout or any other specific. i checked on AppCompatActivity and on simple Activity and they return different types of ViewGroup.